# How to Continue Loop after exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, exception

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
line = """ अशा किंमतीवर खरोखरच चांगला कुकर आहे ok are you sure how are you आधुनिक तंत्रज्ञानासह हे सुलभ आणि सुरक्षित are you आहे இது அற்புதமான தரம் மற்றும் சூப்பர் தயாரிப்பு."""

def split_line(in_line):
    line_sp = line.split(" ")
    line_two = [" ".join(line_sp[i:i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(line_sp), 3)]
    return line_two

#print(split_line(line))
try:
    for i in split_line(line):
        blob = TextBlob(i)
        print (blob.translate(to = 'en'))
except:
    print ("same language found not translated")
```

**This is language Translation code some times text blob throw error so I used try/except block so my code stops when print error message but I want to continue this loop after catching exception**

Comment: Move the try-except block inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the try except block inside the for (if the error is raised by `TextBlob(i)`):

```py
for i in split_line(line):
    try:
        blob = TextBlob(i)
        print (blob.translate(to = 'en'))
    except:
        print ("same language found not translated")
```

This will make the for run until it ends even if an error has been raised in it.

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this will print "same language found not translated" every time that an error has been raised in the try.